# How to configure InfiniteScroll with my (Porto) theme?

Tags: ajax, custom-theme

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I installed the InfiniteScroll extension by Strategery as suggested in my post here:

[How to load less products on the mobile/tablet front page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230479/how-to-load-less-products-on-the-mobile-tablet-front-page/231826?noredirect=1#comment323193_231826)

On the Github page of the extension ( https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll ) it says:

**If you have a different theme other than the default, you will need to copy the default theme files to your custom theme folder and configure the plugin by going to System / Configuration / Strategery / InfiniteScroll.**

So the extension is there on the back-end but it does not seem to work on the front end. I searched the Internet on InfiniteScroll with Magento Porto but am unable to find a solution. How would one do what it says above? The configuration fields are as follows:

Selectors:

```
Content: .category-products ((Selector for the element that surrounds the items you will be loading more of.))
Pagination: .toolbar .pager  ((Selector for pagination))
Toolbar: .toolbar ((Selector for the toolbar (normally pagination, sort-by and display type are inside here))
Next: .next ((Selector for the link to the next page.))
Previous: .previous ((Selector for the link to the previous page.))
Items (grid mode): .products-grid ((Selector for all items you'll retrieve.))
Items (list mode): .products-list
```